# Doesn't share client area with any other window application

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I want to make a dialog such that it doesn't share its client area with any other application. For this i have stick it on top of the screen and top of all other window in Z order  with

`this->SetWindowPos(&wndTopMost, 10, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE);`

Now i need that **all other applications appear below** it so that it doesn't cover menu or top pane of any other window application.

Any Help Would Be really Appreciated.

Comment: This `this->SetWindowPos(&wndTopMost, 10, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE)` set the window on topmost , what problem are you facing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you want to implement an appbar, so you have to use [SHAppBarMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762108%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Example (Here `hwnd` - is your windows handle. This windows should have WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW style for this to work):

```
#include <Shellapi.h>
#define APPBAR_CALLBACK  (WM_USER + 0x01)
APPBARDATA pData;
RECT rt;
```

....

```
GetWindowRect(hwnd,&rt);
pData.cbSize=sizeof(pData);
pData.hWnd=hwnd;
pData.uCallbackMessage=APPBAR_CALLBACK; 
pData.uEdge=ABE_TOP;
pData.rc=rt;
SHAppBarMessage(ABM_NEW,&pData);
SHAppBarMessage(ABM_SETPOS, &pData); 
MoveWindow(pData.hWnd, 
           pData.rc.left,
           pData.rc.top, 
           pData.rc.right - pData.rc.left,
           pData.rc.bottom - pData.rc.top, 
           TRUE);
```

To disable this mode you should call

```
SHAppBarMessage(ABM_REMOVE,&pData);
```

Comment: what is the use of it. i have a dialog i just want to act as task pane when maximize.

Comment: @Heena, I have added an example.

Comment: it is somewhat working but the thing it is moving down all application but my application also goes down with them. where should write this code. right now i am writing it in `OninitDialog()`

Comment: @Heena, your window should have WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW style, otherwise it will be moved down too.

Comment: I think WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW disable the default menu styles also mentioned in this refrence:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Heena maybe you mean title bar? Because menus don't depends on window style, but title bar do.

Comment: but menu image i.e. blue bar is disappeared.

Comment: @Heena if you talking about system menu then you right, it's icon is disabled (but the menu itself can be accessed by pressing ALT+SPACE)